# Defining Wix properties and values based on VS active configuration

Tags: wix, wix3

How can I define Wix properties and values that change depending on which Visual Studio configuration is active?  e.g. For our release build, var x = 1 and for the export build, var x = 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We pass properties into WiX from the wixproj files using

```
<DefineConstants>configuration=$(Configuration)</DefineConstants>
```

In a PropertyGroups section. Then you can use them inside wix as $(var.configuration)

```
<?if $(var.configuration) = Debug ?>
  <?define x=1 ?>
<?endif ?>
```

The WiX help file has a whole section on preprocessor stuff, give that a look for other things you can do.

Answer (score 6):

I am using WiX 3.10 and `$(var.Configuration)` just worked for me.

Comment: Helpful link from @user797717 post below: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrock/archive/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Project Reference Variables for that.
No need to specify constants.

**Sample steps:**

1. Add a project reference (of the application) to your setup project

Right Click 'References', 'Add References'

2. Use project reference values in your wxs file

> $(var.ProjectName.Configuration)

```
<?if $(var.ProjectName.Configuration)  = Debug ?>
  <?define x=1 ?>
<?endif ?>
```

Resources:

[Complete list of Candle preprocessor variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrock/archive/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables.aspx)

[Using Project references and variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html)