# Include MajorVersion etc in filename (OutputName) when building MSI file (wix project)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, wix, windows-installer

In my Defines.wxi I have:

```
<?define MajorVersion="1" ?>
<?define MinorVersion="08" ?>
<?define BuildVersion="11" ?>
```

In my MyProject.Setup.wixproj I have:

```
<OutputName>MyProject</OutputName>
<OutputType>Package</OutputType>
```

Is it possible to include the version variables in the filename somehow, so that my file can be named MyProject.1.08.11.msi?

This didn't work (no such variable is defined):

```
<OutputName>MyProject-$(MajorVersion)</OutputName>
<OutputType>Package</OutputType>
```

This didn't work (no such variable is defined):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)$(OutputName).msi" DestinationFiles="C:\$(OutputName)-$(MajorVersion).msi" />
</Target>
```

It seems very clear to me that $(MajorVersion) is not the correct way of fetching the definition from the Defines.wxi file. What is?

---

**Update**

I tried to put this in MyProject.Setup.wixproj:

```
<InstallerMajorVersion>7</InstallerMajorVersion>
<InstallerMinorVersion>7</InstallerMinorVersion>
<InstallerBuildNumber>7</InstallerBuildNumber>
```

...

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>PrebuildPath=..\..\obj\prebuild\web\;InstallerMajorVersion=$(InstallerMajorVersion);InstallerMinorVersion=$(InstallerMinorVersion);InstallerBuildNumber=$(InstallerBuildNumber)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And this in Defines.wxi:

```
<?define MajorVersion="$(var.InstallerMajorVersion)" ?>
<?define MinorVersion="$(var.InstallerMinorVersion)" ?>
<?define BuildVersion="$(var.InstallerBuildNumber)" ?>
<?define Revision="0" ?>
<?define VersionNumber="$(var.InstallerMajorVersion).$(var.InstallerMinorVersion).$(var.InstallerBuildNumber)" ?>
```

Didn't work either. Got these error messages:

- The Product/@Version attribute's value, '..', is not a valid version.
  Legal version values should look like 'x.x.x.x' where x is an integer
  from 0 to 65534.
- The Product/@Version attribute was not found; it is
  required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, and it works!

**Setup.Version.proj**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <InstallerMajorVersion>55</InstallerMajorVersion>
        <InstallerMinorVersion>66</InstallerMinorVersion>
    <InstallerBuildVersion>$(BuildNumber)</InstallerBuildVersion>
        <InstallerBuildVersion Condition="$(InstallerBuildVersion) == ''">0</InstallerBuildVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**MyProject.Setup.wixproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="Setup.Version.proj" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputName>MyProject_$(InstallerMajorVersion)_$(InstallerMinorVersion)_$(InstallerBuildVersion)</OutputName>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    <DefineConstants>InstallerMajorVersion=$(InstallerMajorVersion);InstallerMinorVersion=$(InstallerMinorVersion);InstallerBuildVersion=$(InstallerBuildVersion)</DefineConstants>
    ...
```

**Defines.wxi**

```
<?define MajorVersion="$(var.InstallerMajorVersion)" ?>
<?define MinorVersion="$(var.InstallerMinorVersion)" ?>
<?define BuildVersion="$(var.InstallerBuildVersion)" ?>
```

Comment: so... after trying out quite a lot, I found it works as described, moreover the **defines.wxi** is not necessary. however I was stuck for a while because I did copy-paste the `<DefineConstants>` bit from the web, and somehow there was a special character or something VS did not accept - I always got the `var.InstallerMajorVersion not found` error. after all it works great, imho really elegant solution!

Comment: just identified another potential error: you want to make sure the `<DefineConstants>` tag is not defined in another `PropertyGroup`, else you get a `var.InstallerMajorVersion not found` error.

Comment: If you change the version number and your projects are loaded in a Visual Studio solution with the WiX Visual Studio Extension installed, you have to close and reopen the entire solution for the change to take effect. Somehow the <Import> data sticks around even if you unload and reload the WiX project.

Comment: after some experiments... if you place the property/properties directly in the wixproj, then you only have to reload the project, instead of reopening the whole solution (VS2022 Community)... I like the Idea, baut apparently the "Import" is not meant to support this goal :-)

Answer (score 16):

This common task should be simplified in future versions of WiX!

This solution combines @Wimmel's and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400868/referencing-a-wixvariable-defined-in-a-wix-library-project-from-a-wix-setup-proj).  It draws the version from a target .exe, and otherwise does not store version numbers in files; it doesn't rename the output file in post-build.  But, it is necessary to update the property ProjectDefineConstants, from which the candle arguments are derived (in wix.targets).  Otherwise, updating only the TargetPath property does not change the inputs to candle.exe.

***.wixproj:**

```
<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <!-- Read the version from the to-be-installed .exe -->
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="path.to.primary.exe">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AsmInfo" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>

  <!-- Create the MSBuild property $(VersionNumber) -->
  <CreateProperty Value="%(AsmInfo.Version)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="VersionNumber" />
  </CreateProperty>

  <!-- Create the WiX preprocessor variable $(var.VersionNumber) -->
  <CreateProperty Value="$(DefineConstants);VersionNumber=$(VersionNumber)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="DefineConstants" />
  </CreateProperty>

  <!-- Update the MSBuild properties $(TargetName), etc. -->
  <CreateProperty Value="$(SolutionName)-$(Platform)-$(VersionNumber)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
  </CreateProperty>
  <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName" />
  </CreateProperty>
  <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetPdbExt)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPdbName" />
  </CreateProperty>
  <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
  </CreateProperty>
  <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetPdbDir)$(TargetPdbName)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPdbPath" />
  </CreateProperty>

  <!-- Update the MSBuild property from which candle.exe args are derived -->
  <CreateProperty Value="
    Configuration=$(ConfigurationName);
    OutDir=$(OutDir);
    Platform=$(PlatformName);
    ProjectDir=$(ProjectDir);
    ProjectExt=$(ProjectExt);
    ProjectFileName=$(ProjectFileName);
    ProjectName=$(ProjectName);
    ProjectPath=$(ProjectPath);
    TargetDir=$(TargetDir);
    TargetExt=$(TargetExt);
    TargetFileName=$(TargetFileName);
    TargetName=$(TargetName);
    TargetPath=$(TargetPath);
  ">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="ProjectDefineConstants" />
  </CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

***.wxs**

```
<Product Id="*" Version="$(var.VersionNumber)" ... >
  ...
</Product>
```

Comment: Excellent.  Best solution here.

Comment: @l33t why? what's the problem with this solution? Your link doesn't work for me currently...

Comment: @Steve Mitchell thx this worked for me. Is there an easier way to crawl to the project executable file than this: `$(ProjectDir)..\MyName\bin\$(Configuration)\MyExeName.exe`? Also, is there a possibility to add "Beta" to the msi name if the setup was compiled with debug binaries?

Comment: @Nicolas, try this link: http://web.archive.org/web/20150416052138/http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4555/

Comment: @l33t thx for the link! I checked that `candle.exe` prints `-d"TargetFileName=Correct Modified Name Including Version.msi"` for me, so I assume this is fixed.

Comment: `GetAssemblyIdentity` only works for .NET assemblies. It does not read the `VS_VERSIONINFO` data on native binaries. T_T

Answer (score 10):

In your .wixproj file. Add the following section just before the `</Project>` tag.

```
<!-- rename the output msi with Version number -->
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="[Path of the main assembly with the assembly version number you want to use]">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Copy SourceFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" DestinationFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName)_%(AssemblyVersion.Version).msi" />
    <Delete Files=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" />
  </Target>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to define the variables in your MSBuild script, and have it update Defines.wxi at build time, as in [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301225546/http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/a-custom-task-for-building-wix-under-msbuild-tfs/).

In your MSBuild script, you could define the version properties as follows:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion>08</MinorVersion>
    <BuildVersion>11</BuildVersion>
    <WixConfigPath>.\Defines.wxi</WixConfigPath>

    <_VariableDefinitions>
      <Root>
        <VariableDefinition Name="MajorVersion" NewValue="$(MajorVersion)" />
        <VariableDefinition Name="MinorVersion" NewValue="$(MinorVersion)" />
        <VariableDefinition Name="BuildVersion" NewValue="$(BuildVersion)" />
      </Root>
    </_VariableDefinitions>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="UpdateWixVars">
    <WixVarSubstitution SourceFile="$(WixConfigPath)" VariableDefinitions="$(_VariableDefinitions)"/>
  </Target>
```

Then running the UpdateWixVars target will update the version numbers in Defines.wxi with the version numbers specified in your MSBuild project.

Note that I could not find an actual compiled dll with this custom build task, so I had to create it by:

1. Download the source [from here](http://www.hempel.cx/Misc/WixVarSubstitution.cs). Build it and name the file Tranxition.BuildTasks.dll.
2. Add the reference to the build task like so:

   ```
   <UsingTask TaskName="WixVarSubstitution"
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Tranxition\Tranxition.BuildTasks.dll"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would love to fix it without using Tranxition. I updated my questions with my latest attempt which is somewhat similar. Do you have any input on that?

Comment: while this answer works, it involves manually updating a file for each build, I prefer the answer below which automates the process

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to read the .wxi file from the .wixproj file. So you have to use another way to specify the version. I can give an example where I read the version from a assembly included in the installer, and use that version to rename the msi;

Open the .wixproj file in an editor and add a `ReadVersion` target:

```
  <Target Name="ReadVersion">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="bin\program.exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Message Text="AssemblyVersion = %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)" />
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName) %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
```

This reads the version from `bin\program.exe`, displays it for debugging purposes, and changes the TargetName, TargetFileName and TargetPath.

After the line containing `<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />`, add the following to inject this target into the build process:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>ReadVersion;$(BuildDependsOn)</BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I updated my question with my latest attempt. It might be clearer now.

Comment: Then you have to use `DefineConstants` in a wixproj `PropertyGroup`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/627279/33499

Comment: yes i did that too, pasted it now. looks correct to me, but still get that error

Comment: this is a good solution, since it automatically includes the version number of the main assembly in the setup filename rather than having to manually update a file.

Comment: For me, this worked in isolation but not with my bootstrapper project. The bootstrapper, using a project reference to the msi, was still looking for the installer's outputname.targetext...not targetfilename.

Comment: Perfect! I just had to give the relative path of my main assembly (e.g. ..\bin\MyAssembly.dll) and the installer was named with the version!

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this seamlessly by implementing these two answers:

- First, update your project's `AfterBuild` task to rename the WIX-built MSI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716409/374198
- Then, update your WIX project to automatically use the verison number of the assembly you're packaging: https://stackoverflow.com/a/641094/374198

The other answers are much too complex!

PS: If you want to drop the fourth digit, following semantic versioning, you can do it like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="..\Path\To\MyProject\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\MyProject.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyInfo" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <In>%(AssemblyInfo.Version)</In>
        <Pattern>^(\d+.\d+.\d+)</Pattern>
        <AssemblyVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</AssemblyVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Move SourceFiles="bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\MyProject.msi" DestinationFiles="bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\CodeGenerator-$(AssemblyVersion).$(Platform).msi" />
</Target>
```

This will create an MSI named, for example, `MyProject-1.2.3.x64.msi`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889431/374198) for more.

Comment: I think renaming the MSI will cause problems: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robmen/2004/12/08/why-does-changing-the-name-of-your-msi-file-require-a-major-upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

This is a full example of a wixproj file where you can set a version number in the UI and use that to modify the output msi file name.

In Visual Studio (e.g. 2015):

- define a version number in "Define preprocessor variables" in the
  project properties window. I've entered VersionNumber=1.14 for this
  example;
- unload your project in the solution explorer;
- right click your project in the solution explorer and select edit yourproject.wixproj file;
- add code in the Target Name="BeforeBuild" element as shown below.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" InitialTargets="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
      <ProductVersion>3.10</ProductVersion>
      <ProjectGuid>PROJECT-GUID</ProjectGuid>
      <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
      <OutputName>my project</OutputName>
      <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
      <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
      <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
      <!-- These constants can be set in the UI -->
      <DefineConstants>VersionNumber=1.14</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
      <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
      <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
      <DefineConstants>VersionNumber=1.14</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
        <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
        <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
      </WixExtension>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' != '' " />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets') " />

    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <!-- This extracts the version number from a setting in the UI -->
      <!-- This method comes from: geekswithblogs.net/alexhildyard/archive/2013/03/09/passing-data-between-msbuild-and-wix.aspx -->
      <ItemGroup>
        <DefineConstantsKVPairs Include="$(DefineConstants)" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <!-- Evaluate each key/value pair with task batching, then make a conditional assignment -->
      <PropertyGroup>
        <VersionNumber Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(DefineConstantsKVPairs.Identity)').Contains('VersionNumber='))">$([System.String]::new('%(DefineConstantsKVPairs.Identity)').Split('=')[1])</VersionNumber>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <CreateProperty Value="$(OutputName)-$(VersionNumber)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
      </CreateProperty>
      <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName" />
      </CreateProperty>
      <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
      </CreateProperty>
    </Target>
  </Project>
  ```